# INSERT SELECT sql statement - how to fetch data from two other tables in one statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, insert

Beginner SQL student here.

I have three tables:

1. Client
2. Account
3. Owns

In `Owns`, I have two columns `client number` and `account number` and I want to add all client numbers from the `Client` table to the first column and all account numbers from the `Account` table to the second column.

How can I do it in one statement?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like outer join.

Some sample data (dummy tables, of course; only necessary columns):

```
SQL> select * from client;

CLIENT_NUMBER
-------------
            1
            2

SQL> select * from account;

ACCOUNT_NUMBER
--------------
           100
```

Using CTEs that utilize `row_number` analytic function whose result (the `rn` column) is then used as join condition, create such a statement:

```
SQL> insert into own (client_number, account_number)
  2  select client_number, account_number
  3  from (with
  4          n_client as
  5            (select client_number,
  6                    row_number() Over (order by client_number) rn
  7             from client
  8            ),
  9          n_account as
 10            (select account_number,
 11                    row_number() over (order by account_number) rn
 12             from account
 13            )
 14          select c.client_number, a.account_number
 15          from n_client c left join n_account a on a.rn = c.rn
 16       );

2 rows created.
```

Result is then:

```
SQL> select * From own;

CLIENT_NUMBER ACCOUNT_NUMBER
------------- --------------
            1            100
            2

SQL>
```

Note that, if `account` has more rows than `client`, you'll have to switch to right join (or keep left, but substitute tables' order).